# CRM 2011 : Permission denied error on reloading the Parent page from child page

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to reload the Parent page from child page on save.  I am using the below code to refresh it.

window.parent.opener.location.reload(true);

This code is working fine for the first time I save the child record. But if i am staying on the same child page and modified something on the page then saving the record. now i am getting the error as Permission denied.

This error is coming because, in the code "window.parent.opener.location.reload(true)" is not able to find location value.

the location value is coming as {...}.

Any help is appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Once the opener is refreshed the child handle is void. To get around this you need a stable none refreshing opener or parent.

If the parent window also has an opener or it’s an iframe that has a stable parent you can use it to hold reference to the first and second level windows.
i.e. Opener 1 / Parent 1 (none refreshing) -> Opener 2 (your parent) -> Child window (CRM form)

After each window is reloaded / refreshed you can go back to Opener 1 to re-connect with your windows.